# Toggle visibility in Antd form

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, antd

I need to display certain inputs when an option from the dropdown menu is selected. The dropdown menu consists of three options, Blood Pressure, Weight and Temperature. When the user selects an option, the input fields relating to that option need to be visible and the rest hidden.

For example when the user selects Blood Pressure, the systolic and diastolic input fields need to be visible, the temperature and weight fields need to be hidden.

```
<Form.Item label="Vital">
              {getFieldDecorator("vital", {
                rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please select a vital!" }]
              })(
                <Select placeholder="Select a option">
                  <Option value="bloodPressure">Blood Pressure</Option>
                  <Option value="bodyWeight">Body Weight</Option>
                  <Option value="bodyTemperature">Body Temperature</Option>
                </Select>
              )}
            </Form.Item>
 <Form.Item label="Weight">
              {getFieldDecorator("weightValue", {
                rules: [
                  {
                    required: true,
                    message: "Please input a weight"
                  }
                ]
              })(<Input placeholder="Weight Value" />)}
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item label="Temperature">
              {getFieldDecorator("tempValue", {
                rules: [
                  {
                    required: true,
                    message: "Please input your oral temperature"
                  }
                ]
              })(<Input placeholder="Temperature Value" />)}
            </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item label="Systolic">
          {getFieldDecorator("systolic", {
            rules: [
              {
                required: true,
                message: "Please input the Systolic value"
              }
            ]
          })(<Input placeholder="Systolic Value" />)}
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item label="Diastolic">
          {getFieldDecorator("diastolic", {
            rules: [
              {
                required: true,
                message: "Please input the Diastolic value"
              }
            ]
          })(<Input placeholder="Diastolic Value" />)}
        </Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use css property `display: none`, to hide `Input` fields on certain condition. e.g you can use condition (`vital` being option selected):

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form.Item label="Vital">
        {getFieldDecorator("vital", {
          rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please select a vital!" }]
        })(
          <Select placeholder="Select a option">
            <Option value="bloodPressure">Blood Pressure</Option>
            <Option value="bodyWeight">Body Weight</Option>
            <Option value="bodyTemperature">Body Temperature</Option>
          </Select>
        )}
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item label="Weight" style={vital !== 'bodyWeight' ? { display: 'none'} : {''}}>
        {getFieldDecorator("weightValue", {
          rules: [
            {
              required: true,
              message: "Please input a weight"
            }
          ]
        })(<Input placeholder="Weight Value" />)}
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item label="Temperature" style={vital !== 'bodyTemperature' ? { display: 'none'} : {''}}>
        {getFieldDecorator("tempValue", {
          rules: [
            {
              required: true,
              message: "Please input your oral temperature"
            }
          ]
        })(<Input placeholder="Temperature Value" />)}
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item label="Systolic" style={vital !== 'bloodPressure' ? { display: 'none'} : {''}}>
        {getFieldDecorator("systolic", {
          rules: [
            {
              required: true,
              message: "Please input the Systolic value"
            }
          ]
        })(<Input placeholder="Systolic Value" />)}
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item label="Diastolic" style={vital !== 'bloodPressure' ? { display: 'none'} : {''}}>
        {getFieldDecorator("diastolic", {
          rules: [
            {
              required: true,
              message: "Please input the Diastolic value"
            }
          ]
        })(<Input placeholder="Diastolic Value" />)}
      </Form.Item>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

P.S., Please note style in each `Form.Item`