# How can I hide or show a field in ReactJS (using antd components)?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm looking to hide an input field on the basis of selected value of another in an antd form. I am referring [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55254147/toggle-visibility-in-antd-form)  (seeing how some people have upvoted (and accepted) [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55261073/806256). But, it's not working for me. Maybe it's because I'm using it in a dynamic form setup?

Anyway, here's my code (I'm trying to hide the `business_name` field on the basis of `status`):

```
<Form initialValues={{relative: [{"status": "Business", "business_name": "ABC inc"}, {"status": "Studying"}]}}>
    <Form.List name="relative">
        {(fields, {add, remove}) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    {fields.map(field => (
                        <div>
                            <Form.Item
                                {...field}
                                name={[field.name, 'status']}
                                fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'status']}>
                                <Select>{["Business", "Studying"].map(status => (<Option value={status.value}>{status.label}</Option>))}</Select>
                            </Form.Item>

                            <Form.Item
                                {...field}
                                style={status === 'Business' ? {display: 'inline'} : {display: 'none'}}
                                name={[field.name, 'business_name']}
                                fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'business_name']}>
                                <Input placeholder="Business Name"/>
                            </Form.Item>
                        </div>))}
                </div>)}}
    </Form.List>
</Form>
```

Thank you for reading. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which field do you want to hide, and on the basis of which variable?

Comment: @LukeStorry clarified in the question as well - I'm trying to hide the `business_name` field on the basis of `status`

Comment: And your code that does `style={status === 'Business' ? {display: 'inline'} : {display: 'none'}}` is not working?
What does the style look like in the Inspector when you open it in chrome?

Comment: It's always evaluating to false. As in, the inspector shows `display: 'none'` (and when I flip the condition to `status !== 'Business'` it always shows `display: 'inline'`)

Basically, it's not picking up the value for `status` I think.

Comment: You component code is malformed, and I'm almost certain that `status` is undefined as written. Please modify the CodeSandbox link below to provide a minimal working example of your component, so that I may provide additional feedback.

https://codesandbox.io/s/malformed-dynamic-form-component-blfr2

Comment: @CesarNapoleonMejiaLeiva Thank you. You were right, there was an error that came about cause of me trying to make a longer code shorter for brevity. Lesson learnt. Anyway, I've fixed those here: https://codesandbox.io/s/malformed-dynamic-form-component-sbgo4?file=/index.js:0-2172

Comment: I suspect that you are right - `status` does indeed seem to be undefined, but then how and where can I define it?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for clarifying your intent.

I managed to hack together a working example at the CodeSandbox link below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/antdhidingfieldonadynamicform-nro1g?file=/index.js

In short, the `Form` values can be accessed via the `form` instance method `.getFieldValue`. Since you are using a dynamic form, the argument you must pass to `getFieldValue` is a `NamePath[]`. This will retrieve the value of `status` for the appropriate field object in the field list.

However, since the component wasn't updating properly as the value of `status` changed, I had to use the `onValuesChange` event handler on the `Form` component which is constantly changing a boolean value triggers `useEffect` to update the `Form` component on any Form field value change.

If you have any further questions, please let me know.

P.S. A less hacky approach would be to hide the `Input` by using a `isHidden` state variable that would be updated and does cause the component to rendered within `onValuesChange` (isHidden would be an array of booleans - false to show the input, true to hide it) ... you would access the appropriate boolean via the `fieldKey` index.